# Calculate bacteria number program in python

Tags: python-3.x

Bacteria B replicates itself each 2 minutes, write a program that asks users to enter two numbers: the initial B bacteria number and a period of time (in minutes). Calculate and print out the total number of B bacteria after this period.

How to do. I did like below but the result is wrong. Because bateria replicates itself each 2 minutes then I multiply it with time.

```
b = int(input('How many B Bacterias are there? '))
t = int(input('How much time will we waits (minutes)? '))
r = b * 2 * t
print ('After',t,'minutes(s) we would have',r,'B Bacterias')
```

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ROeS.png)

Comment: Nice puzzle. What's your question?

Comment: You should check out the Help Center for Stack Overflow. It says "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." So no one will answer this question as it is currently phrased. Show what you have tried and say what your trouble is first and someone might then help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @UmaKanth Sorry this is the first time of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have b bacterias at the t time like this:

```
 t    b

 0    b
 1    b
 2    b * 2
 3    b * 2
 4    b * 4
 5    b * 4
 6    b * 8
 7    b * 8
 8    b * 16
```

and so on.

So your formula is `r = b * 2 ** math.floor(t/2)` and the code will be:

```
import math
b = int(input('How many B Bacterias are there? '))
t = int(input('How much time will we waits (minutes)? '))
r = b * 2 ** math.floor(t/2)
print ('After',t,'minutes(s) we would have',r,'B Bacterias')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function to calculate the number of bacteria is wrong, this is a textbook example of an exponential function.

should be `r = b * 2 ** (t/2)`

You need to take the time t and divide it by the division time of 2 minutes to get the number of divisions that occurred.

By raising 2 to this number you get the total offspring of one bacterial cell and this multiplied by the initial number of bacteria is your answer

Comment: use `t // 2` to get integer division on both Python 2 and 3.